# Pandas - How to convert from float64 to timedelta and customize the output?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have a DF with the following columns:

```
datetime     datetime64[ns]
objid                 int64
delay        timedelta64[ns]
```

An example of the output for the delay is: `

```
0 days 00:04:59
```

For some reason, when I load this DF into dcc.Store session variable,

```
data = df.to_json()
return data
```

and read it back in another callback,

```
df = pd.read_json(data)
```

it returns the following types:

```
datetime    datetime64[ns]
objid                int64
delay               float64
```

now the same example as above, the delay output is:

```
299000.0
```

I am not sure why it's returning float64, instead timedelta64 (maybe because of some NaNs?).

So I'm doing:

```
df['delay'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['delay'], unit='s')
```

and the output is:

```
P3DT11H3M20S
```

what I understand it differs from the original result, even on the iso format.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I convert from float64 to timedelta64[s], and customize the output to `%d %H:%M:%S`?

Comment: `unit="ms"` ... I think would work

Comment: Ok! Yes, It fixed part of the issue. Now I am receiving the correct value over isoformat: P0DT0H4M59S. How can I format the output to %d %H:%M:%S? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *datetime* and *delay* are being changed to **ms** when using `to_json()`.  Convert it back using `astype()`

```py
import json
d = list(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,7,1), dt.datetime(2020,7,2), freq="15min"))
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime":d, "objid":[random.randint(0,100) for x in d], "delay":d - np.roll(d, 1)})

print(df.dtypes)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(df.to_json()))
print(df2.dtypes)
df2 = df2.astype({"datetime":"datetime64[ms]","delay":"timedelta64[ms]"})
print(df2.dtypes)
print(df2[:10].to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
datetime     datetime64[ns]
objid                 int64
delay       timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
datetime    int64
objid       int64
delay       int64
dtype: object
datetime     datetime64[ns]
objid                 int64
delay       timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
           datetime  objid             delay
2020-07-01 00:00:00     59 -1 days +00:00:00
2020-07-01 00:15:00     14   0 days 00:15:00
2020-07-01 00:30:00     42   0 days 00:15:00
2020-07-01 00:45:00     29   0 days 00:15:00
2020-07-01 01:00:00     85   0 days 00:15:00
2020-07-01 01:15:00     37   0 days 00:15:00
2020-07-01 01:30:00     59   0 days 00:15:00
2020-07-01 01:45:00     61   0 days 00:15:00
2020-07-01 02:00:00     63   0 days 00:15:00
2020-07-01 02:15:00     14   0 days 00:15:00
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work, but since I have some rows with NaN, I am receiving the following error: ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer. Any suggestion to work only on the filled rows?

Comment: @iops simplest way is `df2["delay"] = df2["delay"].fillna(0)` before `astype()`. Clearly choose default value that makes sense for you.  I simulated this with `df.loc[5,"datetime"] = np.nan
df.loc[7,"delay"] = np.nan`

Comment: I just filled the NaN with 0, and it's working! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

your "timedelta" is in ms, not s, so use `unit="ms"`

you can get your desired format as follows

```
timedeltas = pandas.to_timedelta([299000,301000],unit="ms")
print(timedeltas)
print(timedeltas.map(str)) # maybe close enough?
fmt = "{days} {hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}"
exact = timedeltas.map(lambda timedelta:fmt.format(**timedelta.components.__dict__))
print(exact)
```